# Fields and codes in Apache FTP log

Tags: apache, ftp, logging

Where can I find information about the fields and codes in Apache's FTP logs?

I am curious about what the "189" here means and the "a _ o r" also.

```
Sun Jul 04 14:29:37 2010 0 xx.xxx.xx.xxx 189 /foo/bar/baz.php a _ o r foo@foo.com ftp 1 * c
```

My google-foo failed me in locating this info.

Where can I read up on these codes?

Comment: Might be more suited at serverfault.com? Never knew there was such a thing as an 'apache ftp server'... Are you sure that's the one providing FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it for you, seemed eerily familiar to wu-ftpd format: http://wu-ftpd.therockgarden.ca/man/xferlog.html

189 = filesize
a = ascii transfer
_ = no special action
0 = outgoing
r = authenticated user

Still don't believe it's Apache, but hey :P

Answer (score 0):

I looked and failed too. But I can make an educated guess:

- the 189 looks like a file size, as seen in a directory.
- the a _ o looks like a set of Unix file permissions: All, Group, Other . That the Group permission is an underscore may mean that the file has no group permissions.
- the r? It could mean "read only". But I'm *really* guessing there.